# Split fastq read into 10G mini files, assembler not accepting as fastq format

Tags: linux, split, bioinformatics, genome, sequence-alignment

I split a 52G fastq file into 10G chunks with the following code:

```
split -b 10G /home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering/AfterQC/good_reads/SRR530529.good.fq outputfile
```

This produced the following files:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm  10G Aug 11 13:48 outputfileaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm  10G Aug 11 13:49 outputfileab
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm  10G Aug 11 13:50 outputfileac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm  10G Aug 11 13:51 outputfilead
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm  10G Aug 11 13:52 outputfileae
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm 1.6G Aug 11 13:53 outputfileaf
```

When I was attempting to assemble "outputfileab", with Velvet, I get the following error message:

```
velveth: /home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering/AfterQC/good_reads/split_SRR530529_file/outputfileab does not seem to be in FastQ format
```

Strangely, both velveth and velvetg was used normally to assemble the first 10G read i.e. "outputfileaa".

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

`split` by file size rather than line counts does just that, and will split in the middle of a line if the byte limit is reached. velvet has a check to assert if every fourth line starts with `@`, so this check will fail considering the split method, which is why we are seeing this happen on the second file and not the first. I would suggest you `split` this file by line count passing the `-l xxxx` flag.

Comment: I used the code: `wc -l SRR530529.good.fq` and got 774,551,052 lines. This is a lot of line, how would one accurately split that amount of lines into smaller more manageable files? Would dividing this number by 4 by passing `split -l 4 SRR530529.good.fq` work? Surely this would create a HUGE number of smaller 4-liner files @benjessop

Comment: You wouldn't split by line counts of 4, rather than into line counts that are divisible by 4.

Comment: Just to clarify, for example: `split -l 4000000 in.fastq`

Comment: Sorry @TimurShtatland, I used the following code: `split -l 193637763 SRR530529.good.fq` that gave me 4 data files each 13G in size. I divided the total lines (774,551,052) by four to get length 193637763.

Comment: total 52G
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm 13G Aug 21 20:42 xaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm 13G Aug 21 20:56 xab
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm 13G Aug 21 21:12 xac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bilalm bilalm 13G Aug 21 21:26 xad

Comment: That would not work. Do not divide the total number of lines by 4.  The number after ‘-l’ has to be divisible by 4. So any number like this: 4, 8, 12, etc will work. This is because one fastq record has 4 lines.